# createUserWithEmailAndPassword throwing FirebaseAuthException with "unknown" error code

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing with Flutter on Web.

The following is the piece of code generating the exception:

```
@override
  Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> registerWithEmailAndPassword({
    required EmailAddress emailAddress,
    required Password password,
  }) async {
    final emailAddressStr = emailAddress.value.getOrElse(() => 'INVALID EMAIL');
    final passwordStr = password.value.getOrElse(() => 'INVALID PASSWORD');
    log.d("$emailAddressStr $passwordStr");
    try {
      return await _firebaseAuth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: emailAddressStr,
            password: passwordStr,
          )
          .then((_) => right(unit));
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      log.e(e.code); // This prints "unknown"
      log.e(e.message); // This prints "An unknown error occurred: FirebaseError: Firebase: The email address is already in use by another account. (auth/email-already-in-use)."
      if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        return left(const AuthFailure.emailAlreadyInUse());
      } else {
        return left(const AuthFailure.serverError());
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log.e("Failed to register");
      // TODO: provide better error message
      return left(const AuthFailure.serverError());
    }
  }
```

Just trying to manage all the excepions with FirebaseAuth but strangely when I try to create an user that already exists, instead of getting the error code

> auth/email-already-exists

I get

> unknown

However the message seems to be correct:

> An unknown error occurred: FirebaseError: Firebase: The email address is already in use by another account. (auth/email-already-in-use).

I could parse the error message but it's not the way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a recent issue that occured a couple of times already in the past as well when FirebaseAuth needs to update with latest flutter version.

You can refer to this github issue: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10966

In the meantime I would recommend that you implement the parsing you are mentionning in order to avoid any similar issue in the future. The bug itself should be patched in the next version of FirebaseAuth if I understand correctly the last post in the issue. And when patched it will get back to your usual error management using the correct error codes.

```
if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
...
} else if (e.code == 'unknown' && e.message.contains('auth/email-already-in-use')) {
...
} else {
  return left(const AuthFailure.serverError());
}
```

Comment: Reading the GitHub issue seems that I fell into the same bug. Thank you!